# Django - how to have dependent select fields manually

Tags: python, django, dependencies

I am new in django (and python as well).

I want to have a dependent select field for state and city in admin . I know the feature Grouped Selects in django smart selects can do this. But this method render the options from the database which is not what I looking for.

I have the dependent data from the external source (json format), and using javascript to populate the regarding data.

So, how do I create the select field and add a class to it (for js selector)?
should I create a empty text field and using js to convert it to select field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using django autocomplete light, it is a fairly solid select-field chaining tool that is good for both model relationships and remote data sources.

This is a link to the documentation for the remote data integration.
http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote.html